# passing variable ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page that has 3 sections. I'm using ui-router, and I'm using a abstract view to get the vehicle object

```
  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard',
      url: "vehicle"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-wizard.html'
      controller: 'VehicleWizardCtrl'
      abstract: true

  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.info',
      url: "/info"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-info.html'
      controller: 'VehicleInfoCtrl'

  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.proof',
      url: "/proof"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-proof.html'
      controller: 'VehicleProofCtrl'

  .state 'dashboard.home.vehicle_wizard.validate',
      url: "/validate"
      templateUrl: 'views/vehicle-validate.html'
      controller: 'VehicleValidateCtrl'
```

Here's the controller :

```
angular.module 'entrenousApp'
.controller 'VehicleWizardCtrl', ($scope, $state, vehicle) ->

vehicle.get().then (result) ->
  if result
    $scope.vehicle = result[result.length - 1]
```

In the second page : 'proof' I need to compute a field based on a variable in the vehicle object.
Where should I do this : 
1/ when doing the submit from the first page, and adding the calculated variable as a scope object, but then  if I refresh the proof page, I lose the value
2/ when loading the proof page, but then I don't seem to be able to access it from the controller on the page load, but I can access the vehicle object from my view.
Guess it has something to do with the object not being loaded.

Comment: 1: when you refresh any page, you would lose any data that is not saved (either on server or localStorage).  2: where do you load the vehicle object? and what do you load it into?  can you post that controller code?  sounds like you will need to wait for the loader promise to resolve before trying to access it in your controller.

Comment: if you need to persist data through page refresh, consider using URL stateParams...  `url: "/proof?theValue"`

Comment: @plong0 I load the vehicle object in the VehicleWizardCtrl from an external API. How do I wait for the loader promise to resolve ?

Comment: if you are accessing the API with angular's `$http` service, it would look something like `$http.get('/vehicles/'+vehicleId).then(function(data){ $scope.vehicle = data.vehicle; });`   Another way could be to do `$scope.$watch('vehicle', function(vehicle){ console.log('Vehicle Loaded!', vehicle); });`

Comment: I decided to go with the watch method for now which doesn't make me send a extra request to my back-end. I will try to use a resolve in the future.

Comment: You could also try with an event.  Where the controller that loads the vehicle does like: `$broadcast('vehicleLoaded', vehicle)` and the other does: `$scope.$on('vehicleLoaded', function(e, vehicle){ $scope.vehicle = vehicle; });`